# Get property from another class function?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    //file classA.php
    class A {

        private $B;
        public $data;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->B = new B();
        }

        public function readA(){            
            $this->data = $this->B->readB();
            print $this->data;
        }

        public function sendB(){
            return "WORD";
        }
    }

    //file classB.php
    class B {

        private $A;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->A = new A();
        }

        public function readB(){
            return $this->A->sendB();
        }
    }   

require_once .... classA.php
requier_once .... classB.php

$classA = new A();
$classA->readA();
```

I wanna use classes with multiple dependences.

Can't use instance methods or extends classes.

How can i get function result and send it back to the same class from another?

Comment: where is the problem? What in your code does not work as you expect it?

Comment: in class B `readB()`: `return $this->A->sendB();` EDIT: changed $A to A

Comment: `Call to undefined method B::sendB()
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function readA() on null`

Comment: Nope :(
`Call to undefined method B::sendB()`

Comment: I think you have to either extend or use for what you want to achieve to work

Comment: I want to understand why this example doesn't work.
Why i cant get returned object from another class?

Comment: the problem is that on construction you create each other class. It's an endless loop.

Comment: At the top of ur script, try use classname; then you should be able to call that classes methods post initialization in constructor. That's how i'ld do it anyway

Comment: if you comment `//$this->B = new B();` in class A it'll work

Comment: So what i should do to make this code work. 
Call A class not in construct function?

Comment: Nope...  `Call to a member function readB() on null`.
That's the reason why i asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an endless loop of object creation:
When you create class A it'll create an Object of Class B, that will create another object of Class A again, that will create an Object of Class B,....
-> Memory Error

So if you get rid of `$this->B = new B();` in `__construct()` of class A it'll work with that change:

You had:

```
    // in class B
    public function readB(){
        return $this->sendB();
    }
    // it needs to be:
    public function readB(){
        return $this->A->sendB();
    }
```

Complete working code:

*EDIT: Now with readA() in class A, but creation of class B out of constructor.*

```
<?php
class A {

    private $B;
    public $data;

    public function __construct(){
        //  $this->B = new B();
    }
    public function readA(){   
        $this->B = new B();
        $this->data = $this->B->readB();
        print $this->data;
    }
    public function sendB(){
        return "WORD";
    }
}

//file classB.php
class B {

    private $A;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->A = new A();
    }

    public function readB(){
        return $this->A->sendB();
    }
}   

$B = new B();
echo $B->readB();
$A = new A();
echo $A->readA();

?>
```

Comment: Yep! This works. But what if i need to create one more B class object in another class which will be called from the same index.php?

Comment: that depends on what the classes do. Of course you can create a class C. Or you don't create class B on creation of A, but with a seperate method.

Comment: No no no. I can't refactor code because of interface class. function ReadA must be in A class. But thanks anyway.

Comment: anyway, there's a circle you've created. As I don't know what the classes are, I can't give a logical solution. This is the solution to why your code didn't work.

Comment: __NOTE__ this kind of depending of other classes is not recommended. Because when calling `readA()` you don't know, that it depends on class B. It would be better to pass an object of B to `readA($B)`.

Comment: @МишаДестроер *"Yep! This works."* - The answer should be marked as accepted. *"But what if i need..."* - that's another question entirely and "after the fact", IMHO.